# Magento 2.3 install issue with php warning

Tags: installation, composer

I am trying to install Magento 2.3 by using composer install / update. I got below error.

Any idea what problem I am facing?  I did try to use different php & composer version. Still having this error. Please help.
I did try to google the Warning message, but not much result I can find.

[image]

I am running:
composer 1.x
php7.3
nginx server

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html is the setup instruction. What are your prerequisites that lead you to an already populated app/code folder upon install?

Comment: I suppose doing an update from 2.3.1 to  2.4.3 however I got issue while update. So I want to have a complete install again for 2.3.1 I didn't remove the old files. is this the main cause of the issue?

Comment: Quite sure it is. I'd rather run an actual clean install (as per the steps given in the docs). Then verify 'blank' Magento is  running, merge your composer.json, copy over app/code, design (and i18n), run `composer update` (for the changes in composer.json) and run the full `setup:upgrade` process. If you then must, import your 'old' database; this should lead you back to the starting point.

Comment: Also, check out the PHP (and other) requirements for what you are trying to accomplish since 7.3 might not be supported for either, current nor target, version (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html).

Comment: If I in this saturation? I should delete everything? any specific folder I can delete? because I do have github, env.php, composer.json...etc and there has a lot media files as well?

Comment: I can't and won't just suggest you on *deleting everything* remotely as I don't know your setup and security/fallback strategies.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I think there is a no easy way to fix it. I have to go for hard way, which start from an empty folder